# How can I make a "where" query using the select and order options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I make a "`where`" query using the `select` and `order` options?

Like this:

```
Shipment.where(:invoice_id => nil)
```

To use:

```
Shipment.find(:all, :order => "file_number", :select => "id, file_number")
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work fine:

```
Shipment.select('id, file_number').where(:invoice_id => nil).order(:file_numer)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward :-)

```
Shipment.order('file_number').select('id, file_number')
```

Comment: #all will evaluate to an Array rather than an AR relation.  It should be moved to the end of the method chain or simply omitted.

Comment: Thanks. I normally use Mongoid. There `.all` returns a criteria (relation-like object).

Comment: Ah, likewise thanks for the insight into Mongoid, with which I'm not familiar.